# iOS DatePicker disable background

Tags: ios, datepicker

I have a button that when pressed slides in a uidatepicker, however if you keep pushing the button i keeps pushing a new date picker on top of the previous one. one on top of the other, continually per button press. Pretty much I want to disable everything on the view except the slide in date picker. Is there a way to disable the background and just have the date picker be interactive? Im sure there is an easy fix I'm missing. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really set for answering how to disable the background, but one way to prevent multiple datepickers from appearing would be to set and check the state of the datepicker.

When the datepicker appears you set a `bool` to `YES` indicating that there is currently a datepicker active. Now, everytime the button is pressed you can check if there already is a datepicker visible. When the datepicker is removed, simply set the `bool` to `NO`.

Cheers!

Comment: Great solution, thanks for help. I knew it was something easy. BOOL check was perfect